# open a powershell window at a screen position

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open a new powershell window, which i can do fine. However I cannot set it's position on the screen.

I'm using the following:
https://superuser.com/questions/1324007/setting-window-size-and-position-in-powershell-5-and-6

but I am getting the following error:
Method invocation failed because [Window] does not contain a method named 'MoveWindow'.

Here is the powershell script:

```
Function Set-Window {
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
        a process window.

    .DESCRIPTION
        Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
        a process window.

    .PARAMETER ProcessName
        Name of the process to determine the window characteristics

    .PARAMETER X
        Set the position of the window in pixels from the top.

    .PARAMETER Y
        Set the position of the window in pixels from the left.

    .PARAMETER Width
        Set the width of the window.

    .PARAMETER Height
        Set the height of the window.

    .PARAMETER Passthru
        Display the output object of the window.

    .NOTES
        Name: Set-Window
        Author: Boe Prox
        Version History
            1.0//Boe Prox - 11/24/2015
                - Initial build
            1.1//JosefZ (https://superuser.com/users/376602/josefz) - 19.05.2018
                - treats more process instances of supplied process name properly

    .OUTPUT
        System.Automation.WindowInfo

    .EXAMPLE
        Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X 2040 -Y 142 -Passthru

        ProcessName Size     TopLeft  BottomRight
        ----------- ----     -------  -----------
        powershell  1262,642 2040,142 3302,784   

        Description
        -----------
        Set the coordinates on the window for the process PowerShell.exe

#>
[OutputType('System.Automation.WindowInfo')]
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    $ProcessName,
    [int]$X,
    [int]$Y,
    [int]$Width,
    [int]$Height,
    [switch]$Passthru
)
Begin {
    Try{
        [void][Window]
    } Catch {
    Add-Type @"
          using System;
          using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
          public class Window {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
          }
          public struct RECT
          {
            public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
            public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
            public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
            public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
          }
"@
    }
}
Process {
    $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
    $Handles = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle   ### 1.1//JosefZ
    foreach ( $Handle in $Handles ) {                              ### 1.1//JosefZ
        if ( $Handle -eq [System.IntPtr]::Zero ) { Continue }      ### 1.1//JosefZ
        $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {            
            $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left            
        }
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
            $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
        }
        If ($Return) {
            $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
        }
        If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Passthru')) {
            $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If ($Return) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
                $Size = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                $TopLeft = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left, $Rectangle.Top
                $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                If ($Rectangle.Top -lt 0 -AND $Rectangle.LEft -lt 0) {
                    Write-Warning "Window is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                }
                $Object = [pscustomobject]@{
                    ProcessName = $ProcessName
                    Size = $Size
                    TopLeft = $TopLeft
                    BottomRight = $BottomRight
                }
                $Object.PSTypeNames.insert(0,'System.Automation.WindowInfo')
                $Object            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please edit your question and post your script here. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to post a [mcve], not your entire script.

Comment: We don't go somewhere else (even if it's another [se] site) to investigate your question. Please provide a [mcve] here, and ask a specific question - [Can anyone help?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576) isn't one.

Comment: Sort of  interesting that the code you linked is related to the specific error you're getting. It's even verbatim in the post. So your question as written now is *Can someone post an answer for me here for this question asked somewhere else?*, which is clearly inappropriate for this site.

Comment: Ken White... I would normally agree but I've changed the scripted as the stated User32.dll -> user32.dll but I am getting the error. So I thought I would ask for help as I cannot figure it out

Comment: Ask this... ( I've changed the scripted as the stated User32.dll -> user32.dll ), Why did you change it? You are not saying what OS you are on. I can state that this code works as is without change relative to the original on Win10 and WS2012R2

Answer (score 0):

Could you use vbscript?

Look at this answer https://superuser.com/a/325611

Replace the cmd.exe by powershell.exe and call the script using `cscript.exe script.vbs`